# Is inclusive monadic first order logic decidable?

Tags: logic

Standard first order logic assumes non-empty domains. There exists a so-called inclusive first order logic that allows empty domains. Inclusive logic invalidates some of the rules used for prenexing formulas.

It is known that the monadic fragment of standard first order logic is decidable. Is the monadic fragment of inclusive first order logic also decidable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the monadic fragment of inclusive first-order logic is indeed decidable. The key fact is that it is decidable to tell whether a monadic (or general, in fact) first-order sentence is true in the empty structure; this is a good exercise.

So to tell if $\varphi$ is a validity in the inclusive sense, we first ask whether $\varphi$ is a validity in the standard sense. If not, we're done - $\varphi$ has a countermodel. If $\varphi$ *is* a validity in the standard sense, we then check if $\varphi$ holds of the empty structure. If it doesn't, $\varphi$ isn't a validity in the inclusive sense, and if it does, then $\varphi$ is a validity in the inclusive sense.

In general, there is no real complexity difference between a standard logic and its inclusive variant, because they differ only at one structure; in order to get a meaningful difference for a logic $L$, it would need to be the case that checking whether an $L$-sentence is true of the empty structure is "hard", and that rules out all the natural (in this context) logics. For example, checking whether an *arbitrary finite-order* sentence is true of the empty structure, is decidable!